# Getting the cues from a VTT chapters track with Video.js

Tags: javascript, video.js, webvtt, cue-points

I would like to get the cues from the chapters file loaded in my Video.js object. I've already find how to get the track but I need its `id` in order to access it.

```
player.textTracks().getTrackById(<trackID>);
```

I found out where the `id` is defined in the Video.js 5.14.0 library:

```
// video.js/dist/video.js (line 19195)
var trackProps = {
  id: options.id || 'vjs_track_' + Guid.newGUID(),
  kind: options.kind || '',
  label: options.label || '',
  language: options.language || ''
};
```

It seems that you can define your own `id` by passing an object to the function:

```
// video.js/dist/video.js (line 19178)
var options = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : {};
```

I load the chapter track as follow:

```
<track kind="chapters" src="chapters.vtt" srclang="en" default>
```

I've read that you can dynamically add track files but you will have to reload the Video.js object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all the tracks and then get one that is of type `chapters`:

```
player.on('loadedmetadata', function () {
    var tracks = player.textTracks(),
            chapterTrack;

    for (var i=0; tracks.length > i; i++) {
        if ('chapters' === tracks[i].kind) {
            chapterTrack = tracks[i];
        }
    }

    console.log(chapterTrack.cues);
});
```

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/text-tracks.md#working-with-text-tracks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The `textTracks` object returns no track item even though I can see my track in its `tracks_` attribute from the console when using `console.log(vvplayer.textTracks());`. This attribute may be private now.

Comment: Just tested with video.js 5.14.0 & 5.14.1. This method works for me, but, it looks like the text tracks aren't always ready when the video.js ready callback is invoked so I had to wrap the code in a listener for the `loadedmetadata` event, that made it work reliably for me at least. Updated the answer with that.

Comment: Many thanks for your tests and your quality answers, I wish I had a debugging tool that give information regarding asynchronous calls.